# Airflow - Get End Time of DAG run

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Is it possible to get the actual end time of a dag in Airflow? By end time I mean the exact time the last task of the dag gets completed.

For observing the performance of our application, I should write the time taken by DAGs to a file and compare them for different loads. I got the start time by context["dag_run"].start_date. But when I print context["dag_run"].end_date, I get None.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Where are you trying to get the information?  (ie: in dag's success_callback, through API, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DagRun` will never have an end date until the execution is completed and a final state is met `(success/failure)` to get this detail, you will have query the backend database to fetch the `end_date` as exactly as it is displayed in the UI (using `connection_id: airflow_db`) it can get a little complicated if you're new to Airflow and it needs to be done in a separate DagRun all together.

If you're okay with something close to the actual end_date of the dag_run, you can use the solution described by @lealvcon.

To elaborate on his answer, you have to assign `on_success_callback` on the final task in your DAG and you can get the current datetime (`datetime.utcnow()`) as a measure of the closest DagRun `end_date`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a callback function on the DAG's `on_success_callback` parameter?

maybe it says `None` because at the time it fetches the end date the DAG hasn't finished yet